# Store location data using Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data, cllocation

I was wondering what approach is recommended for storing an array of CLLocation objects (forming a route or path) in a Core Data database? Is serialization a good approach or would you recommend to store the CLLocation objects in a separate model that has relationship to a "route" model?

The problem with serializing the array of locations is that you don't have easy access to the individual locations. On the other hand, storing each location of the route/path as a separate entry in the database seems to result in a large database and might result in slow performance.

I'm curious to hear your suggestions.

Bart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that best fits my needs is to store the location data as doubles by storing latitude and longitude separately. Searching is slightly more complex as a result, but this approach seems better than any other approach I have come across so far.

I have to note that there are reports of developers experiencing problems with this approach in terms of problems with the accuracy (significant digits) when retrieving the stored data. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585331/storing-high-precision-latitude-longitude-numbers-in-ios-core-data) is one such example.

Answer (score 1):

For one of an app I've code, I've store them to a string as described in the Google map API.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

[Polyline algorithm](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm.html)

Comment: Thanks Charles. I'll definitely check this out.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot properly query the location data if you store them as a string. My solution at the moment is to store the location data as binary data and store a proxy for search purposes.